# Resize images in python using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize a set of images, approximatively 366, so I created a script that I tested first on 3 and it was successful.

The issue is when I process the whole folder, it returns me this error :

```
resizeimage.imageexceptions.ImageSizeError: 'Image is too small, Image size : (275, 183), Required size : (399, 399)'
```

My script is supposed to iterate an entire folder, resize images then store the output files in another folder:

```
import os

from PIL import Image

from resizeimage import resizeimage

path = "/Users/sigc2sige/PycharmProjects/helloworld/photos"
size = (399, 399)

for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open('/Users/sigc2sige/PycharmProjects/helloworld/photos/'+file, 'r+b') as f:
        with Image.open(f) as image:
            cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            cover.save('/Users/sigc2sige/PycharmProjects/helloworld/photos_2/'+file, image.format)
```

I did use this instruction:

`thumb = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)` but I believe that it crops images instead of resizing them.

If you have any ideas about how to solve this issue, it would be great.

Comment: You haven't include the code in your `resizeimage` module nor the full traceback, so it's difficult (impossible?) to answer your question.

Comment: Why are you using `resizeimage`? PIL provides `resize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downsampling an image (making it smaller) is one thing, and upsampling (making it bigger) is another thing.  If you want to downsample, ANTIALIAS is a good choice, if you want to upsample, there are other filters you could use.

```py
import os

from PIL import Image

from resizeimage import resizeimage

path = "/Users/sigc2sige/PycharmProjects/helloworld/photos"
size = (399, 399)

for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open('/Users/sigc2sige/PycharmProjects/helloworld/photos/'+file, 'r+b') as f:
        with Image.open(f) as image:
            if (image.size) >= size:
                cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                cover.save('/Users/sigc2sige/PycharmProjects/helloworld/photos_2/'+file, image.format)
            else:
                cover = image.resize(size, Image.BICUBIC).save('/Users/sigc2sige/PycharmProjects/helloworld/photos_2/'+file, image.format)
```